# Getting UCase, Trim, Left libary errors in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a application that opens excel files. When I run a macro function in my excel that was opened with the application. I'm getting Compile error "Can't find project or library" on the "UCase" "Trim" "Left" just to name a few. In my macro functions, I have multiply cases of using the above functions. I also have references to "Visual Basic For Application", "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library", "OLE Automation", "Microsoft Office 12.0 Library", Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library."

If I run excel by itself without the application, there is no errors. Is there any explanation to why this is happening? Libraries mix match? Works fine for the developer and a few but as for the rest of users, they will get these errors.

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VBA AndAlso IsNot VBScript.  Please use only relevant tags.  Guidance is provided on them.

Comment: Likely one of your workbooks has a "missing" reference - that often results in functions from another library getting flagged.

Comment: @TimWilliams I checked the references when there was the error and there are none that was missing.  I did try however checking Microsoft Soap 3.0, and the error went away, I unchecked that library, and it still worked after that. weird.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely due to the 'Visual Basic for Applications' in the Tool reference refers to non-presence library.  This may happen if the developer use the library in their customized directory instead of default library.

There are 2 means to solve the issue.

1. Make global replacement of all string related functions (Format, Left, Right, Mid, Trim etc) with prefix VBA. e.g. VBA.Left. This will force the use of functions within standard library.
2. Move all your excel sheets to another new workbook and then, select the 'Visual Basic for Applications' from Tool reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's because those methods belong to Excel Application so that you must call them by preceding their name with the Excel object name (and possibly with its relevant member, too) you must have instantiated before

for instance

**example 1:** late binding

```
Option Explicit

Sub LateBindingExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object 'declaring your application object as of "Object" type doesn't require any reference to Excel library

    ' open an Excel session
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' call Excel application WorksheetFunction.Trim()
    MsgBox xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Trim(" see    how spaces    get trimmed    by    this   function  ")
End Sub
```

**example 2:** early binding

```
Option Explicit

Sub EarlyBindingExcel()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 'declaring your application object as of "Excel.Application" type requires adding Excel library reference to your project

    ' open an Excel session
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' call Excel application WorksheetFunction.Trim()
    MsgBox xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Trim(" see    how spaces    get trimmed    by    this   function  ")
End Sub
```

one sensible difference between the two binding "styles" is that the latter allows you exploiting IntelliSense features while the former doesn't

Comment: I open the excel on my application using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file.xlsm") could that contribute to missing libarary? I don't want to open it with excel.application because evertime I open excel, it creates a new instances of excel and that instance doesn't get close in the task manager and so forth clogs up memory until the application is closed.

Comment: by the way. the methods "Trim, Left, UCase" are used in VBA libararies, why would opening excel from the application cause error in VBA in excel? This is only happening to other users using the application. as for me and a few, it works just fine.

Comment: While I don't know `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` method at all, I can add that you can open one excel instance only and handle multiple sheets. And you're right: `Trim()`, `Left()` and `UCase()` are VBA function also (though they result may differ from their Excel counterpart)  so that you should use them "directly" in a VBA environment. You may give the "unique Excel application" a shot...

Comment: I'm opening multiply workbooks but can't get the instance close once user closes excel which clogs up memory so process.start opens and close excel instance once user closes it.

Comment: I tried the early binding and with no success. But what I did find out that if I refresh the reference in excel, there's no error, so I've made a method to check and uncheck a reference in that excel and BAM! no errors.

Comment: so you have users interact with Excel instance... well, you didn't specify that, and the scenario is entirely different... and unknown to me so that I couldn't help you along that path.